# Can anyone identify what’s happening to these leaves? Insects? Rabbits? Chemicals?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, pests, peppers

Trying to decide what is going wrong here. These are pepper plants. Recently added perlite and oyster shells to improve water drainage and raise PH.  Could that result in this problem? Might it be insects? Rabbits?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible it was frost damage? How are the plants progressing?